# How can I do this program faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, execution-time

I am trying to create a program where a user inputs two numbers - a base and an exponent, while exponent is a binary number. Then prints out the last two digits. My code is working well, but according to the time execution it is not the fastest way to do it.

This is my code:

```
base = int(input())
exponent = int(input())

def binaryToDec(binary): 
    decimal, i = 0, 0
    while(binary != 0): 
        dec = binary % 10
        decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i) 
        binary = binary//10
        i += 1
    return decimal
exponent = binaryToDec(exponent)
result = base ** exponent
result = abs(result)%100
print(result)
```

For example, the output of `3` and `1010` should be `49`.

Another example:
Input:
`111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`
`111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

Output:
`31`

I expect the program to work faster in doing so, how can I do this?

Comment: why these complications?? `int('101010',2) == 42` etc...

Comment: @dangee1705 edited, 10 in binary is 1010, so 3^10 and then prints out the last two digits of the result, so 49

Comment: @lenik I am working on a couple of problems, so I need to follow the instructions

Comment: what's your current execution time, and what is your goal? on my PC it takes about a few us to get things done, how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @lenik on one of the tests that I did the wall time was 122.2% and CPU time 0.0% I think this might be because i'm using the `**` for the result instead of a more efficient method

Comment: Please don't delete the code from your question. You can delete the entire question if you don't want it around any more.

Answer (score 0):

*Found the following speed up.*

**Posted Method**

```
def binaryToDec(binary): 
    decimal, i = 0, 0
    while(binary != 0): 
        dec = binary % 10
        decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i) 
        binary = binary//10
        i += 1
    return decimal
```

**Modified Method (alternative to using pow(2, i))**

```
def binaryToDec_modified(binary): 
    decimal, i, p = 0, 0, 1          # modification
    while(binary != 0): 
        dec = binary % 10
        binary = binary//10
        decimal = decimal + dec * p  # modification
        p <<= 1
        i += 1
    return decimal
```

*Timing (~ 73% faster) *

```
n = 100010001101001 # (15 digits)

%timeit binaryToDec(n)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 µs per loop

%timeit binaryToDec_modified(n)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.03 µs per loop
```

Comment: i have a program that is testing this, and I was told it is because I am using the `**` function instead of Horner's model

Comment: on a side note is there a quicker way to convert binary to decimal? without creating a function for this?

Comment: @hernal--int(n,2) converts binary string n to decimal.  For instance int("1010', 2) = 10.  [Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-decimal-vice-versa-python/)